# Semicolon separated list of types in XSD

Tags: regex, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xsd

I have an `XML` attribute that must accept a semicolon separated list of strings. I'd like to create an `XSD` to specify all possible values for that input.

For example:

```xml
<User role="Admin;Publisher;Editor" />
```

I know that I can create a simple type like so:

```xml
<xs:attribute name="role">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Admin"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Editor"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Proofreader"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Publisher"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

But that restricts it to only a single value.

I know that I can use a regular expression as well. But how would I combine the two? If I use a regex like `[^;]+` then how can I validate the values?

Can I make a regex that is a list of those `role` enumerations?

Or just a regex that forces it to be a list of those enumeration values, in any order, with semicolons in between? (`A;C;B`, `A`, `;B;A`, etc, where `A`,`B`, and `C` are specified words.)

Comment: Is it possible to refactor your schema design so that role is a repeating element instead?  That would be a better design if possible.

Comment: Alternatively you could split up the attributes into something like IsAdmin, IsEditor, etc.  But the repeating element would still be preferable IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the schema, it's locked in as a semicolon separated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan Field's answer is correct:  the right thing to do is fix the design of the XML.

If you can't do that (why not?  how on earth did you get involved in a project where a broken design is frozen before it can be fixed?  do you really want to be in this project?), a simple workaround is to transform the data from the specified format to a more easily validated format before validation.

- You can have `role` as a child, as suggested by Dan Field.

  ```
  <User>
    <role>Admin</role>
    <role>Editor</role>
  </User>
  ```

  Here, the type of 'role' is the same as the anonymous type of @role in your sample.
- You can have the roles as elements:

  ```
  <User>
    <Admin/>
    <Editor/>
  </User>
  ```

  Here, an xs:all can be used to allow the optional role elements to appear in any order.
- You can have a white-space delimited list of role names:

  ```
  <xs:simpleType name="rolename">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Admin"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Editor"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Proofreader"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Publisher"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="rolelist">
    <xs:list itemType="tns:role"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  ```

Comment: Trust me, I would like to change the schema. But a simple schema is more important than an `XSD` to validate it. That and consulting is all about picking your battles.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible to do this, but not advisable.  You could come up with a restriction that enumerated all possible combinations, for example:

```
<xs:enumeration value="Admin;Editor;Proofreader;Publisher" />
<xs:enumeration value="Admin;Editor;Proofreader" />
<xs:enumeration value="Admin;Editor" />
```

etc.  There would be very many permutations, and as you continue to add more roles the list will grow exponentially.

What you really should consider is refactoring your XML and schema to be something more like the following:

```
<User>
  <role>Admin</role>
  <role>Editor</role>
</User>
```

If you really insist on using attributes still, you could throw the attribute on the role element which might be useful if you wanted to specify children of the role element and not have a mixed content node:

```
<User>
  <role name="Admin"><roleDescription>An administrator of the system</roleDescription></role>
  <role name="Editor"><nodesICanEdit>All</nodesICanEdit></role>
</User>
```

Comment: I agree with your point about refactoring the schema to have a collection of children instead of this attribute list, but unfortunately I can't change the structure at this point.